# How to convert FBV to ListView in Django

Tags: django, django-views

I want to convert the FBV function to ListView. 
But I don't know how to handle the value of slug. 
 
How to get the value of slug in ListView?

**view.py**

```
def category(request, slug=None):
    current_ct = None
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    products = Product.objects.filter(ready=True)

    if slug:
        current_ct = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=slug)
        products = products.filter(category=current_ct)

    return render(request, 'home.html', {'current_ct': current_ct, 'categories': categories, 'products': products})
```

**url.py**

```
path('category/<slug>/', category, name="test"),
```

**get_absolute_url() in model.py**

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("test", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})
```

Comment: It seems to make more sense here to implement this as a `DetailView` on the `Category`, than a `ListView` on `Product`. Especially since then, you do not need to do filtering on a slug yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get access to the parameters passed to the call with `self.args` (for positional parameters) and `self.kwargs` (for named parameters).

That being said, if you use a [**`DetailView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview), you do not *need* to do this yourself at all. Indeed a `DetailView` and all other class-based views that use the [**`SingleObjectMixin`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin) will look for a `slug` and `pk` in these parameters, and do the filtering automatically.

We thus can make it a `DetailView` as:

```
class CategoryDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Category
    context_object_name = 'current_ct'
    template_name = 'home.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context.update(
            categories=Category.objects.all(),
            products=self.object.product_set.filter(ready=True)
        )
        return context
```

Here by overriding the [**`.get_context_data(..)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_context_data), we thus inject extra items in the context we pass when rendering the template.

Comment: How can `self.object.product_set` access the Product model?

Comment: @dinggu: because if you make a `ForeignKey`, Django will automatically add a relation in reverse, that has by default the name `sourcemodel_set`.

Comment: Oh, I fully understand. Thank you so much.